# When should I use polymorphism and has_many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, associations

I hope this doesn't get flagged as too generic or whatever, but I've been trying to wrap my head around these two concepts for awhile and, surprisingly, I haven't found what I'm looking for.

My issue is not so much understanding the concepts, but rather knowing when to use them. Can someone list a few questions I should ask myself that will determine if these associations are the right solution?

How can I know when I need to use each of these?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a situation where 'A has many B' and 'B has many A', e.g. 'a company can have many customers and a customer can have many companies', you have one of two choices:

- Use `has_and_belongs_to_many` when the relationship is nothing more than a simple connection, and when you do not need to store any more data about each connection.
- Use `has_many, :through` when you want control over the join table between A and B. This association gives you the ability to store more information about each interaction, such as when you want to say 'when customer A deals with each company, we want to know how they met, when, etc'.

Polymorphic associations are another case when one table 'can apply to' many other tables. One example is addresses. Say you have customers, companies, and employees. All of these entities have data in common: their address. So, you can create a polymorphic Address table that then connects to all the others. So, sometimes polymorphic tables are jokingly thought of as 'promiscuous' because they can interact with an arbitrary number of other tables at once.

Answer (score 1):

they aren't necessarily related concepts. Has_many, :through is for simplifying the interface for many-to-many relationships, such as:

> passengers have many planes, planes have many passengers

the resulting schema would need a join table, and would look like this:

> - passengers have many itineraries
> - planes have many itineraries
> - an itinerary has a single plane
> - an itinerary has a single passenger

the AR associations could be written thusly:

```
class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :itineraries
  has_many :planes, through :itineraries
end
```

so now you could access all planes a passenger took through the ActiveRecord Query interface thusly:

```
traveler = Passenger.find(1)
traveler.planes #returns all planes associated with that passenger's itineraries.
```

the use of has_many, through: prevents you from having to access the itineraries join table directly when querying, adding, or updating associations.